# Why does URL of gitlab readme.md section not scroll to section?

Tags: hyperlink, gitlab, readme

To reproduce:

1. Create a `README.md` file on `gitlab` repository.
2. Create some headers in the file using `#`, and save it.
3. Get the section link, e.g. scroll to the last header, and click the "link icon" beside it. The browser URL will show something like "https://.../README.md#my-last-header".
4. Copy this URL and paste it in a new browser tab.
5. It's supposed to display the file *then* scroll down to "my last header", but it doesn't scroll. It only displays the file at the top line of it.

Is that a bug?

How to get a URL to a section in Gitlab Reademe.md file that displays the file *and scrolls* to the section?

N.B. It works in `github`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The working link is got as following:

`https://gitlab.com/<user>/<project>/#my-last-section`

Assuming that the `READEME.md` is found on the project root folder directly.

Instead of the link got *when opening the readme.md file*:

`https://gitlab.com/<user>/<project>/blob/main/README.md#my-last-section`

Which either has a bug, or is designed for that!